# Xamarin RadioButton.Content not showing correct content

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to set an image inside a RadioButton like shown at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton

```
<RadioButton>
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <Image Source="icon.png"/>
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

But in app it shows only the text "Xamarin.Forms.Image" instead of the image.

What is wrong? I just did it like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#display-arbitrary-content)

> However, on **some** platforms a RadioButton can display a View,

and

> On Android, RadioButton objects will display a string-based representation of the View object that's been set as content:

Comment: Yes, I missed that part... Now it's working by adding ContentPage.Resources like explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#redefine-radiobutton-appearance